# constructor <class> in class <class> cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, constructor

I am making a new game and I have a problem. When I compile, the terminal says:

```
./Button.java:29: error: constructor Rect in class Rect cannot be applied to given types;
    public Button(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1) {
                                                      ^
  required: int,int,int,int
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

I am not really sure what is going on. As you can see, it says `found: no arguments`
but it also says `Button(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1)`. It seems to contradict itself... I noticed that it started happening once I extended 'Button' off of 'Rect'

please help.

Comment: Did you put super(x0, y0, x1, y1) in the Button constructor?

Comment: Can you please post the code?

Comment: @Dalton I just tried that and it worked thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error message, one can tell that the `Rect` class has a four-argument constructor and it doesn't have a no-argument constructor.

A subclass constructor must call a superclass constructor.  If you don't explicitly call one, then Java will insert an implicit call to the default, no-arg constructor for you.  That is what's failing.  There is no no-arg constructor in `Rect`.

You must explicitly call a superclass constructor here, because there is no no-arg constructor available in `Rect`.

```
public Button(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1) {
    super(x0, y0, x1, y1);
    // Rest of your constructor here
}
```

Comment: thanks... but one other thing: the button constructor does the exact same thing as the Rect constructor.

Comment: If the `Button` constructor is also trying to initialize `x0`, `y0`, `x1`, and `y1`, then it shouldn't.  That logic is already in the superclass constructor (or it should be).  The superclass constructor is already doing that initialization (or it should be).

Comment: oh! thanks so much! i finally got it using your help. by the way, I am new to stackoverflow, but I have been using other people's questions for about a year